# xsl css jquery - hidden div still showing space

Tags: jquery, html, css, xslt

XSL Sample:

```
<xsl:choose>            
        <xsl:when test="../@id='35'">                
            <strong><xsl:value-of select="."/><br /></strong>
        <font class="uportal-channel-text">
        <input name="response35" value="Yes" type="radio" onclick="show()"></input>Yes&nbsp;
        <input name="response35" value="No" type="radio" onclick="hide()"></input>No&nbsp; <br /><p></p>            
        </font>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="../@id='36'">                
            <div class="show1 hidden"><div id="ask-heading"><strong><xsl:value-of select="."/><br /></strong></div></div>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="../@id='37'">                
            <div class="show1 hidden">
                <strong><xsl:value-of select="."/><br /></strong>
                <font class="uportal-channel-text">
                <textarea cols="20" rows="1" name="response37" maxlength="255"></textarea>
                <br />  <p></p>            
                </font>
            </div>
        </xsl:when></xsl:choose>
```

Note the div class=hidden on each section. That jquery and css is this:

```
<style>
        .hidden{display: none;}         
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(){
            $('.show1').removeClass('hidden');
        }
        function hide(){
            $('.show1').addClass('hidden');
        }
    </script>
```

The addClass and removeClass work correctly when the onclick event happens in id=35 section at the top of the xsl choose.

The problem is, the defaulted sections that are class=hidden are showing white space
screen shot:

[image: white space visible above the submit]

When I test this in regular html, the display none works correctly, no space. Any assistance would appreciated. I would like to get rid of that white space and have the submit button up where it belongs under the last question.

thanks in advance

UPDATE:
I see the problem when I view the html - some other template or data call from the DB is adding `<br /><p></p>` to each question.

```
<div class="show1 hidden">
   <strong>Total enrollment:
   <br />
   </strong><font class="uportal-channel-text">
   <textarea maxlength="255" name="response37" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea>
   <br /><p></p></font>
</div>
<br>
<p></p>
```

This falls outisde my div class=hidden

So, once I can eliminate that, it should cooperate.

Comment: What does the resulting HTML (after XSL transformation) look like?

Comment: @MrLister thanks, I see that there are some break tags and p tags falling outside the hidden div, most likely causing my space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing the raw html output there were templates that were included onto the page that had `<br />` markup between them causing the extra space.

Once these were removed, the spacing was removed from the page as it should.